# From a string with repeated under scores (e.g. 1_2_3_4_5_6), split and select 3_4

Tags: python, pandas

The header of my data frame looks like this

```
header = list(data_no_control.columns.values)
header

['MLID_D_08_NGS_34_H08.fsa',
 'MLID_D_25_NGS_38_A11.fsa',
 'MLID_D_36_NGS_41_D12.fsa',
 'MLID_D_37_NGS_42_E12.fsa']
```

I want to change my header to look like this

```
['NGS_34',
 'NGS_38',
 'NGS_41',
 'NGS_42']
```

How can I do this?

Comment: You can use a regular expression. You can use `split()`, slicing, and `join()`.

Comment: What have you tried based on your own research and what went wrong with your attempts? Please [edit] to include code so that we can better understand how to help

Comment: "How can I do this?" Do you not have any ideas yourself? In your question title, you already describe a possible set of steps to solve the problem: split the string on underscores, choose the appropriate ones, and then join them back together with underscores. Which of these steps do you not know how to do? What did you try in order to figure out how to do these things? Also, *what does this question have to do with Pandas?*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
header = ['MLID_D_08_NGS_34_H08.fsa',
 'MLID_D_25_NGS_38_A11.fsa',
 'MLID_D_36_NGS_41_D12.fsa',
 'MLID_D_37_NGS_42_E12.fsa']

new_header = []

for item in header:
    item = item.split('_')
    new_header.append(item[3] + '_' + item[4])

# output: ['NGS_34', 'NGS_38', 'NGS_41', 'NGS_42']
print(new_header)
```

Answer (score 2):

Using `str.extract`:

```
df["col"] = df["col"].str.extract(r'_([^_]+_[^_]+)_[^_]+\.\w+$')
```

Here is a [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/RMd4ey/1).